# Match separated comments in evil mode

Tags: evil, vim-emulation

everyone, I need that emacs matchit in evil mode works like that one works in vim. Let me explain. I have this lines of code

```el
; {{{ matchit
(unless (package-installed-p 'evil-matchit)
  (package-install 'evil-matchit))
(require 'evil-matchit)
(global-evil-matchit-mode 1)
(setq evilmi-ignore-comments nil)
; }}} matchit
```

When I'm at position of closing curly bracket and press `%` nothing happens in Emacs. But vim jumps to corresponding open curly bracket.

Can you please help me with this different behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade to evil-matchit 2.1.4

This is a bug in 2.1.3.

Setup is not necessary. It works out of box now.